# Если функция уже вызвана и вызвана она в $(document).ready(function(), как при вызове какой-либо другой функции убить первую?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, веб-программирование

У меня на странице две формы. Когда я нажимаю на кнопку первой, происходит ajax запрос. Он отправляет код на почту для подтверждения изменения данных.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#btn").click(
    function(){
        getdetails();
        return false;
    }
);});


function getdetails(){
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action_ajax_form.php",
    data: { }
}).done(function( response ) {
    
});}
```

После всплывает вторая форма для вставки кода подтверждения. Пользователь вставляет код подтверждения в форму и отправляет второй ajax запрос.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
$("#confBtn").click(
    function(){
        getdetails2();
        return false;
    }
);});


function getdetails2(){
$.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "action_ajax_form2.php",
    data: "code=" + confInput.value
}).done(function( response ) {
    $("div.testing").html(response);
});}
```

Но почему-то при отправки второй формы срабатывает ajax запрос первой формы! Подскажите способы решения! Наверно нужно как-то во время выполнения 2-ого ajax запроса деактивировать 1-й ajax запрос.

HTML code:

```
Первая форма:

<form method="post" id="ajax_form" action="" >
    <button type="submit" name="submit" id="btn">Изменить данные</button>
</form>

Вторая форма:
 
<form method="post" id="conf_form" class="code_form" action="">
      <input type="text" class="code_inp" name="code_conf" id="confInput" placeholder="Введите код подтверждения">
      <input type="submit" class="code_sbm" name="conf_answer" id="confBtn" value="Подтвердить">
</form>
```

Скорее всего это из-за файла action_ajax_form2.php

```
<?php
session_start();
include 'action_ajax_form.php';

$codeInput = $_POST['code'];

$result;
if($codeInput == $code){
    $result = "НАЙС";
}else{
    $result = "ПЛОХО";
}

echo $code;
echo "<br>";
echo $result;
echo "<br>";
echo $codeInput;
```

?>

include 'action_ajax_form.php' опять выполняет отправку!!! Как из php кода взять только переменную????????

Comment: Покажите ваш HTML код, пожалуйста

Comment: Добавил html код

Comment: может у вас там на странице js в отдельном файле закэшировался и старый код какой-то отрабатывает? ничего тут не должно приводить к такому поведению

Comment: @teran,можно я вам наглядно покажу? Какой-нибудь контакт оставьте. Думаю вы мне сможете помочь

Comment: А эти две формы на разных страницах или на одной?

Comment: На одной странице

Comment: вы считаете адекватным код с матами выкладывать?

Comment: ниче не понятно. все в разброс. Дак отследите в браузере когда, и где стартует вызов второй раз. Открывает devTools -> source, ищите ваш файлик (Ctrl + P) и ставите точки на нужных строчках (при возвах ajax запросов). Когда выполнится первый и остановится на втором - смотрите стек вызовов и узнаете откуда ноги растут. Потом решаете проблему или идете сюда с новыми вводными